# JCA Activation Specification without rar

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere-liberty, java-ee-8, open-liberty, jca

I use liberty application server and want to know , can create custom activation specification (inbound-resourceAdapter) without rar module ?
I want to implement that in war application not ear .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible (both in Liberty as well as in the Jakarta/Java EE specs) to provide an activation specification via a standalone WAR module.  You need to package the activation specification within a RAR module, which can either be a standalone RAR module or a RAR module within an EAR.  Using a standalone RAR module (providing the activation spec) and a standalone WAR module together could be an option if you are willing to do that.